# How to assign a death counter to a Text Mesh on Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to do a 2D platformer with a deaths counter, but I'm facing a problem.
Here is the script I attached to a 3D Text:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class DeathCounter : Respawn
{
    public Text DeathCount;
    public void SetText(int text)
    {
        string deathsS = deaths.ToString();
        DeathCount.text = deathsS;
    }
}
```

And it does nothing. 
I'm asking for help please.
What do I do ?

Here is the "Respawn" script, if needed:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Respawn : MonoBehaviour
{

    public int deaths;

    private Scene scene;

    void Start()
    {
        scene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        if(col.transform.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            deaths = deaths + 1;
            Debug.Log("You are dead");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
        }

    }

}
```

Thanks a lot for your help !
Have a nice day.

Comment: Why do you have 'int text' as a parameter and never use it in the function? Also, where are you calling the SetText function so it is executed?

Comment: Haem, I don't really know... I have seen this part of code on a unity forum so I tried using it... Is it a bad one ? :/

Comment: I'll write a more comprehensive answer, gimme a sec...

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would do is remove the inheriting of `Respawn` from your `DeathCounter` class since it's not extending the functionality of `Respawn`. I would then set the function to use the passed in parameter to set the text value instead.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class DeathCounter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text DeathCount;
    public void SetText(String text)
    {
        DeathCount.text = "Death Count: " + text;
    }
}
```

Then, in your other class when doing your collision check you can pass the death count value as what to set your DeathCount text to.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Respawn : MonoBehaviour
{

    public int deaths;

    //Reference to your DeathCounter script
    public DeathCounter dCounter;

    private Scene scene;

    void Start()
    {
        scene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        if(col.transform.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            deaths = deaths + 1;
            //New line here, with passed in script for updating as a reference
            dCounter.SetText(deaths.ToString());
            Debug.Log("You are dead");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
        }

    }

}
```

**Edit:** One script version...

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Respawn : MonoBehaviour
{

    public int deaths;

    //Reference to your Text, dragged in via the inspector
    public Text deathCount;

    private Scene scene;

    void Start()
    {
        scene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        if(col.transform.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            deaths = deaths + 1;
            //Just update the referenced UI text
            deathCount.text = "Death Count: " + deaths;
            Debug.Log("You are dead");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much ! I will try this and I'll tell you if it works. I'm a bit afraid of doing the wrong things in the editor itself. I'll see. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Maybe if the scripts are on the same GameObject you can use a `dCounter = GetComponent<DeathCounter>();` inside the Start function of the Respawn class instead. Doesn';t really matter so long as you get it referencing your DeathCounter script appropriately.

Comment: It doesn't work :/
I added your script "DeathCounter" to my 3D Text, and the script "Respawn" to my collider box, and now my character doesn't respawn :/

Comment: I did some edits because of spelling error of mine. How are you getting a reference between the scripts? And if you want, this can be simplified to only one script since you don't really need a separate script for updating the DeathCount display. Gimme a sec, I'll edit in the simpler way to do it.

Comment: One script version added. I'm assuming your set up of scripts in the inspector is rather odd since you put the DeathCounter script on to the 3D Text instead of a empty gameobject to hold all your UI update scripts. This may cause referencing issues if not handled properly.

Comment: Hello. Tim, I tried your one script version and I attached the script to the trigger object (the floor of the scene), but I cannot drag and drop the 3D Text into the "Death Count" case. What should I do ? I tried derHugo's solution, but I doesn't work neither.

Comment: @Azuoo Lemme clarify something first... are you using a [UI Text](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Text-text.html) or are you using a [TextMesh](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextMesh.html)? Because the code I displayed uses the UI Text version since I made an assumption based off of you including the UI package.

Comment: You will still need to fix the level getting reloaded like derHugo stated though.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem**

basically lies in the `LoadScene`:

You increase the `deaths` value **BUT** then you reload the scene → you also reload the `Respawn` instance and therefore `deaths` again will have its original value so probably `0`.

You didn't even call the `SetText` method but even if you would when the scene is reloaded also the `Text` component is reloaded and will have the original text like of you hadn't called the `SetText` method at all.

---

**Solution**

I'm order to fix it in this case I would use

```
public class Respawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static int deaths{ get; private set; }

    ...
```

if the value is `static` it is not bound to a certain instance of `Respawn` but "lives" directly in the type `Respawn`. Therefore it keeps its current value also when reloading the scene. The `{get; private set;}` turns it from a *field* into a *property* which can be read by every other class but written only by the `Respawn` class.

Further you **never** want to use something like

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
```

in the Unity main thread. This completely freezes the main thread and if you e.g. later add any animations etc the app will simply freeze completely. Instead use a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) like

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    if(!col.transform.CompareTag("Player")) return;

    deaths += 1;
    Debug.Log("You are dead");

    StartCoroutine(Reload());
}

private IEnumerator Reload()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);

    SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
}
```

Finally you have to set the `Text` after loading the scene so it gets updated also in the reloaded scene.

```
public class DeathCounter : Respawn
{
    public Text DeathCount;

    // automatically called when scene is reloaded
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        DeathCount.text = deaths.ToString();
    }
}
```

---

Sidenote:

In `Respawn` you store a

```
scene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
```

but later never use it but instead anyway use

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
```

so I would get rid of that `Start` method .. it only causes unnecessary overhead.